# connection from ArcMAP to Postgresql, Is ArcSDE required?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

I wan to make a direct connection form Arcmap to Postgresql.

I have ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 on windows (64bit).

So I need to put "pg_client_windows64" libraries in C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\bin. Is this right?

Where to get "pg_client_windows64"libraries from?

Do I need to install ArcSDE?

Comment: You are not very clear in your question about what you are trying to do with pg_client library.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your ArcGIS for desktop 10.1 is 32 bit running on 64 bit os, so you still need to  [use the 32 bit libraries](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=158&f=2291&t=284669).
Yes put them in the bin folder.
No at 10.1 arcsde binaries are installed with desktop. Direct connections are encouraged for all database connections.
Here are the [PostgreSQL supported operating systems](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcsde/10.0/postgresql-system-requirements) from the esri website.
and the [dbms compatibility list here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Client_and_geodatabase_compatibility/003n00000008000000/) with the [client complatibility](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002p000000pv000000).

Comment: ArcGIS PostgreSQL client libraries are now at http://my.esri.com/#/downloads/ (requires login), click "Additional Products" to see them.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly, without ArcSDE, using a query layer: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000027000000

And here is how to define the connection to your DB: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00290000003q000000